# New relic error rate high due to Us based IPs performig invalid search.Issue occuring everyday planning to automate IP blocking in apache

Tags: python, apache, elastic-stack, newrelic, kibana-5

New relic error rate high due to US based IPs performing invalid search in website.I am manually blocking the IPs in apache(temporarily). Issue occurs everyday , need suggestions how to automate the IP blocking process.

Additional info:Logs are monitored in (ELK)Kibana.

Current scenario for blocking IP is greping  IP performing invalid search from access log ,getting country code of IP from "curl -s ipinfo.io/$i/country" and blocking the IPs in apache.

Is there a way to automate the process by getting details from ELK or any Newrelic plugins.Also thinking of writing  scripts for automating.

Comment: Why not fix the underlying issue, and prevent bad searches from breaking your site?

Comment: Its a eCommerce site for particular product . And users are searching similar product of different company.

Comment: It should be possible to prevent any search terms from breaking your site though.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Dowling  for the suggestion.Will check on the options to prevent the invalid search  with developers

Comment: @Ben Dowling it will be great if you suggest with what option we can prevent any search terms in site.Example scenario if site is purchasing Levis products only and user is continuously searching for Wrangler or Lee In case if we prevent the particular search term and aging the end user is performing invalid search continuously(if scripted) will it affect the error rate?

Comment: You need to figure out why a "bad" search term causes problems for your site, rather than immediately returning "0 results".